# AppFabric cache configuration and hosts

Tags: c#, appfabric-cache, distributed-cache

The MSDN Documentation is unfortunately not clear.
I want to know that, if I have say 3 servers in a cache cluster:

CacheServer1

CacheServer2

CacheServer3

Then why do I need to specify each of these servers in my applications' web.config or app.config like so:

```
<dataCacheClient>
  <hosts> 
       <host name="CacheServer1"  cachePort="22233"/>
       <host name="CacheServer2"  cachePort="22233"/>
       <host name="CacheServer3"  cachePort="22233"/>
  </hosts>
</dataCacheClient>
```

?

if there is a leadhost (each of them are by default I believe) then surely it would be the one to manage/distribute the data across the cluster?
This means that if a new node is added to the cluster, then you have to add the host entry into the app config rather than the lead host being able to simply distribute the data across all the nodes as it sees fit?

I thought that you would specify just the lead hosts in the config file and then that lead host distributes the data across the cluster.

am I missing something?

How can I check if the data is being distributed across the cluster?

Comment: Anybody? I am sure people have got this working?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of lead hosts exists only for management of the cluster and not client requests.
Note that lead hosts concept only exists if you are using xml config for appfabric cache. if it is sql, sql is the single point for cluster management. 
There is a minimum quorum of lead hosts which is required for cluster to be up and running.
For small clusters, it is expected to have /2 +1 number of lead hosts for that. Explanation of lead host/ sql cluster management can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790954(v=azure.10).aspx

This is different from managing requests/messages sent by client.

Comment: yes indeed. it all seems to be working now and not sure exactly how I managed to get it working. I see the distribution work as I would have expected and that was a cause for concern initially and why I had specified all the hosts in the config file for the application.